# Bluetooth File Transfer with Nexus 5X Not Working

Tags: 14.04, files, bluetooth

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. The laptop's Bluetooth seems to work fine as I have a remote Logitech keyboard that I have paired with it that works flawlessly.

My problem is with my Nexus 5X which I would like to pair with the laptop to exchange files. The laptop appears to recognize the 5X and correctly identifies it in the Bluetooth devices as a 5X. In Bluetooth settings I can watch when I try to connect and the connection widget goes from "off" to "on" and then immediately back to "off".  I see the same behavior on the Nexus 5X.

If I connect via USB, the laptop connects fine and I can transfer files.
I can connect my 5X and transfer files via Bluetooth to my windows laptop.

Any ideas what I may try next to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open terminal and enter

```
sudo apt-get install bluez-obexd libmulticobex1 libobexftp0 libopenobex1 obex-data-server obexd-client obexfs obexftp obexpushd
```

reboot

Those are the packages installed on my computer and I can browse files on my phone

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my Nexus 5X on Ubuntu 15.10. The only way (which I know of) to overcome the issue is to delete the pairing and re-pair the devices.
I used to have the same problem with my old phone, a Nokia Lumia 920, so I think that there is a bug in Ubuntu Bluetooth pairing.
Hope this helps